# How to cope with large XAML files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to know how to handle large XAML files.

I found this 
[Split one big XAML in number of Sub-XAML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977872/split-one-big-xaml-in-number-of-sub-xaml-files)

which mentions that an xml file can be split in several smaller files.

So my question is: is this the only way to deal (develop + maintain) with larger interfaces / XAML files?

Are there other ways?

I would like to

- have smaller files
- have designer support and visual studio
- making it easier to maintain and update it

Comment: Why do you suspect this is not the best way?

Comment: Because I am a total newbie. Found this solution on my own and never ever found it in the books or tutorial I am studying on. What's more even here when people posts question show sometimes complicated xamls not splitting them in sub-xamls

Comment: You may want to look up Data Templates and Resources.

Comment: Found here http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html that it's a way of replacing attributes. From your comment I get it s another way of splitting xamls  right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the UI from parts is very well possible.

Have a look at:

- UserControls, to reuse UI and logic,
- CustomControls, to reuse UI and logic and allow a developer to apply his own UI design and
- DataTemplates and ControlTemplates, to reuse UI

Because Visual Studio 'understands' these concepts you will have designer and compiler support and you won't need to perform additional build steps.

Comment: It's very possible but is it the most convient way to deal with large xaml? As for how to do it what you says coincides with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977872/split-one-big-xaml-in-number-of-sub-xaml-files

Comment: That depends on your goals. What is 'Convenient' to you might not be convenient others. What is bothering you? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to improve "standing on the shoulders of giants" as Newton said. I can understand that convenience is opinable. That being said I think that if I split xaml in subxaml I can deal with them more easily. Just like having subroutines instead than a single program flow. At the moment I have a single very long xaml and find it difficult to maintain it (find the right point where to make a correction e.g.) and expanding (adding a new component). So i thought that if I split it in several files it might be easier. NO OTHER SOLUTION comes to my mind though.

Comment: By using user controls and templates you will split the file and make it smaller. And you will still have designer support and visual studio will understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thanx in the end even if downvoter and on hold I had what I've been looking for.

Comment: The reason the question got down voted is that it is asking for a "best way" which is an opinion. If you rephrase the question to "how to cope with large XAML files" it might get up votes and be active again

Comment: I edited the question to make it fit the site's goals better. Feel free to rollback the edit

Answer (score -1):

In C# WPF the rule is to have one xaml file by HCI view, so that in MVVM you have a VM for a xaml file.